# Compile Error: Object Required - Search Copy Paste Macro Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro in Excel VBA 2007 that searches through the selected field and if it finds a certain string anywhere in a row, it copies and pastes that row into another sheet.

However, I'm getting a compile error: object required right on the sub level (line 1). My code so far is below.

```
Sub SearchCopyPaste()
'
' SearchCopyPaste Macro
' Searches for a string. If it finds that string in the line of a document then it copies and pastes it into a new worksheet.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W
'

    Dim sourceSheet, destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets(1)               'Define worksheets
    Set destinationSheet = Worksheets(2)

    Dim selectedRange As Range                    'Define source range
    Set selectedRange = Selection

    Dim numRows, numColumns As Integer                            'Determine how many rows and columns are to be searched
    Set numRows = Range(selectedRange).Rows.Count
    Set numColumns = Range(selectedRange).Columns.Count

    Set destinationRowCount = 1                     'Counter to see how many lines have been copied already
                                                    'Used to not overwrite, can be modified to add header,etc

    Dim searchString As String                      'String that will be searched. Will eventually be inputted
    Set searchString = "bccs"                       'Will eventually be put into msgbox

    For rowNumber = 1 To numRows
        If InStr(1, selectedRange.Cells(i, numColumns), searchString) > 0 Then
            selectedRange.Cells(rowNumber, numColumns).Copy Destination:=destinationSheet.Range(Cells(destinationRowCount, numColumns))
            destinationRowCount = destinationRowCount + 1
    Next rowNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: except answer from @Alexandre change this line `Set numRows = Range(selectedRange).Rows.Count` into: `numRows = selectedRange.Rows.Count` and next line accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Set` keyword wrong. In your code above you only need to use it to assign `Worksheet` and `Range` objects, not for integers and strings. Remove the `Set` keyword on those lines.

Also, you're missing an `End If` in your `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however now I am getting an error on the numRows line, saying that Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. I kept the Set keyword on the line that defines the source range.

Comment: You should make another question as this is a different issue. I'd say that you may want to look into your Range() usage. It looks suspicious but I can't put my finger on it. You could also skip that variable and directly use `Selection.` instead of creating a `Range` object.